# Where it is recommended to save files in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am still not very clear in which folder to save the files uploaded by the user such as avatars, or the images of a post etc.

I've already read the guide https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem but couldn't figure out the best solution.

I can safely upload files to:

- `storage / app / folder`

Or in

- `storage / app / public / folder`

For example, I use the following code to load avatars and it is saved in **storage/app/avatars**:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

Comment: If the files are going to be publicly accessible then it's probably worth just using the `public` disk (`storage/app/public` is the default for this disk).

Comment: My project involves the loading of many files, accessible in different types. Let me explain, yes, the user can upload his avatar which is the only action that the user can perform. While a post (uploaded only by the administrator) has preview images that are public and a .zip file that is blocked via .htaccess if accessed directly via url. Can I safely upload the .zip file to storage / app / public / files?

Answer (score 0):

If they need to be publicly accessible they need to end up in `public` some where. If you have setup the storage link then the `public` disk which is set as its root to `storage/app/public` will be accessible via `yoursite.blah/storage` as it is symlinked to the `public/storage` folder

Comment: What kind of "repercussions" can I have by managing each file in storage/app/folder?

Comment: unless you symlinked `storage/app/folder` to `public/somefolder` it won't be publicly accessible ... but not sure what repercussions you are thinking about

Answer (score 0):

normally in this route: *storage/app/public/folder*

Just remind you that if you create a folder, example: avatar and you want to save there all the avatars

you have to register that folder in the filesystems configuration file: *config/filesystems.php*

you have also more examples, in the [filesystem documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

I entered the second line for the avatars, in my controller I save the file like this:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

But keep uploading it to **storage/app/avatars**

```
'links' => [
     public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
     public_path('avatars') => storage_path('app/public/avatars'),
],
```